# Hide Page if it does not have line items to be printed in rtf file

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XUIM.jpg)I'm building a custom print using BIP desktop add-in words and there are two pages. the first page is general information and the second page comes from line items (application used Unifier).

Line items may not have information and I was trying to find a way NOT to print it if there is no data entered into line items.[enter image description here][2]

How to hide or not to print a page in rtf file if it does not have information?

Thanks

Zee

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use an if statement with a count function containing a condition. Put the if statement before the page break. In this example I'm checking if the `INFORMATION` element is not blank and counting the instances of it.

```
<?if:count(LIST_ROW/ROW[INFORMATION!=''])>0?>
...CONTENT...
<?end if?>
```

**Example**

Template
[image]

XML

```
<list_record>
<record>
<record_id>A</record_id>
<list_information>
<information>
<key>1</key>
<value>one</value>
</information>
<information>
<key>2</key>
<value>two</value>
</information>
</list_information>
</record>
<record>
<record_id>B</record_id>
<list_information>
<information>
<key>1</key>
<value></value>
</information>
<information>
<key>2</key>
<value></value>
</information>
</list_information>
</record>
</list_record>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I have tried this but it didn't seems to work. I have hardcoded sentences on the second page and i think this negates the condition all the time.

Comment: Can you share your template and example XML file?

Comment: If the sentences are within the if condition, they wont even exist at time of generation.

Comment: Is there a way to apply the condition for the entire page. if line item empty then do not show the page.

Comment: How to share them. I can't find a way to attach the files! Can you send me your email pls

Comment: I created and tested an example. Works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it does work perfectly for the table values however the issue comes when you have the title for the table. whatever constant description it keeps split from the actual value and print it on the upper page.. see picture above

Comment: first, i had the "department of transportation" description and keep splitting it between pages so i put it in the header but now it split the label of the table.

Comment: If you can find a way to share the files and post a public link here, that would be a great help. Maybe a public read only google drive?